# Creating a class with thread safe functions using InvokeRequired property and Invoke method

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have a class that I created and in the class I do some multi-threading.  Usually to do my multi-threading on a form I would use the following method...

```
//Thread Safe Functions
delegate void Thread_Safe_SendMessage_Progress_Callback(string sProgress);
private void Thread_Safe_SendMessage_Progress(string sProgress)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Thread_Safe_SendMessage_Progress_Callback d =
            new Thread_Safe_SendMessage_Progress_Callback(Thread_Safe_SendMessage_Progress);
        try
        {
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { sProgress });
        }
        catch
        {
            //ObjectDisposedException
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Fire up the thread event
        SendMessageThread_Progress(sProgress);
    }
}
```

Now that works perfect!  At this point I try to bring the multi-threading into a class i made.  When I do that everything seems to be great with the exception of the InvokeRequired property and the Invoke method do not exist within my class.  So using this.InvokeRequired throws an error...  To give my class that property I do this... (Note that m_iThreadID is set in the constructor and when the thread is created to start with)

```
private bool InvokeRequired
{
    get
    {
        //Get the current thread id
        int iThreadID = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        //Compare and return results
        return (iThreadID != m_iThreadID);
    }
}
```

Now the only thing left is the Invoke method...  How do I get that to work?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/09b7285d-3294-483c-ad92-36d202285d43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke` method isn't so "easy" to replicate (side question: why don't you use `BeginInvoke`? I guess you may don't need to raise the event synchronously). You can get the first form in `Application.OpenForms` (copy before use!) and inspect that to check for `InvokeRequired` and `BeginInvoke/Invoke`.

Comment: Thanks Adriano!  Just found my answer out and it was quite easy...  Seeing that I'm under 100 rep still I have to wait another 7 hours before I can answer myself..  :/  Well I have a really easy solution and in 7 hours I will share!

Comment: I'm curious, I had to deal with something like that and  a better and more generic solution is really welcome!

Comment: Adriano, I posted the simple solution and it's working great for me!  Everything is wrapped up in my class!  :)

Comment: So in the end my solution was a bust!  I just took out all of my thread safe functions and made them regular functions. In my case there was actually no reason to have a thread safe function as everything was contained in my class and it worked out for me.  So I just got rid of all the references to Invoke() and InvokeRequired.  I never did find an answer.  :/

Comment: At least now you know what to do when you'll need to process an asynchronous event from another thread (or a BackgroundWorker)! Think positive! :)

Comment: Yea, thread safe functions are easy to do and they have always worked very well for me...  It was just hard trying to keep it all inside a class...  I tried my idea of inheriting the Control object's properties but I also had to account for the InvokeRequired property point out by Hans.  To do this I tried to send the parent threadid as a parameter to my new thread and that way my InvokeRequired property (the one I have in my question) would actually return the correct value for InvokeRequired.  Well then I got issues trying to call Invoke().  The object's window did not yet have a handle.. :/

Comment: I think if you can't make every function thread-safe. Usually UI is NEVER thread safe so when you know a function will be invoked by another thread you pick InvokeRequired/Invoke. But usually I think you don't have to care if you do not play with threads directly (almost all .NET Framework methods aren't thread-safe).